# Grouping Data in a Pandas Merge

Tags: python, merge, pycharm

I have two video game dataframes to merge with an inner join but everything I try I get multiple records for each game when I am trying to group them by name and year.

Is there anything I can do to get one row for each game with data from both tables where it matches the 'Game' key

```
DF_A = pd.merge(ps4, xbox, how="outer")  # Full outer joining the PS4 and Xbox One tables
print(DF_A)  # Checking the dataframe is correct

DF_B = pd.merge(DF_A, all, how="inner", on="Game")
print(DF_B)
```

Current Output is below
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv2J0.png)

Comment: Welcome! It'd be much easier to answer if you could include the contents of your two initial DataFrames. Even better, create example ones to test with. Also, please post any output in a code block in the question rather than an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.